# Fitting a histogram with skewed gaussian

Tags: python, scipy, histogram, curve-fitting

I want to fit histograms with a skewed gaussian.
I take my data from a text file:

```
rate, err = loadtxt('hist.dat', unpack = True)
```

and then plot them as a histogram:

```
plt.hist(rate, bins= 128)
```

This histogram has a skewed gaussian shape, that I would like to fit.
I can do it with a simple gaussian, because `scipy` has the function included, but not with a skewed. How can I proceed?

Possibly, a goodness of fit test returned would be the best.

Comment: what do you mean by skewed Gaussian? Gaussian distribution, by definition, is not skewed.

Comment: @WilliamZhang, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution. It is the more general case.

Comment: As indicated on the Wiki page you pointed out, there's no closed-form solution for maximum likelihood estimation. What you could try is to match the first three moments, or equivalently mean, variance, and skewness, since there are three unknown parameters in this distribution.

Comment: @WilliamZhang, I see. So there is not any ready recipe for this distribution, as in the gaussian case?

Answer (score 6):

You might find lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/)  useful.  This has a Skewed Gaussian model built in.  Your problem might be as simple as

```
from lmfit.models import SkewedGaussianModel

xvals, yvals = read_your_histogram()

model = SkewedGaussianModel()

# set initial parameter values
params = model.make_params(amplitude=10, center=0, sigma=1, gamma=0)

# adjust parameters  to best fit data.
result = model.fit(yvals, params, x=xvals)

print(result.fit_report())
pylab.plot(xvals, yvals)
pylab.plot(xvals, result.best_fit)
```

This will report the values and uncertainties for the parameters amplitude, center, sigma (for the normal Gaussian), and gamma, the skewness factor.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers out there for using the .fit() method of scipy.stats.skewnorm, but that method doesn't allow for initial parameters and is not robust. This lmfit package is better, but I will add that a non-zero baseline may still throw it off. To get it to work on my particular dataset, I used the scipy.optimize.curve_fit first with an ordinary gaussian, which was the quickest way to get the baseline, then subtracted it and refit with lmfit to get the skew.